# Changing PART of an image_tag path dynamically in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord, dynamic

I am building an app where I don't want to store a whole image path in the database, but instead I've named the images to correspond with a record id (2-sm.png, 15-sm.png..etc)

```
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>

   <%= image_tag 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog/img/"#{p.id}"-sm.png', alt: '#{p.name}'%>
   <% end %>
```

I've also tried replacing "#{p.id}" with:

```
   <%= p.id %>
   #{p.id}
   "p.id" <--I didn't really expect that to work...but I'm stuck so, you know...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
<%= image_tag "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog/img/#{p.id}-sm.png", alt: p.name %>
```

Notice the use of double quotes (`"`).